# Creating totals by column in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset of 481K rows x 184 columns. Below is an example table.  I want to be able to have a sales total for each column based on a set of criteria.

```
Name (Criteria = All excl. Jim) = $275 sales
Position (Criteria = All exlc. Associates) = $250 sales
City (Criteria = All excl. Detroit) = $75 sales
```

Ideally the current 184 columns would return as a row with an associated sales value in the second column.  I'm really just trying to figure out where to start with this one.  Thank you for any helping or ideas you may have.

```
         Name  Position   City          Sales
0        Jon   Owner      Detroit       200.0
1        Joe   Manager    Philadelphia  50.0
2        Jim   Associate  Orlando       25.0
3        Jerry Associate  Detroit       25.0
```

Comment: df.sum(axis=1) will sum all the numeric columns in the row, if I understand what you're asking.  See this site:  https://sparkbyexamples.com/pandas/pandas-sum-dataframe-columns/#:~:text=sum()%20to%20Sum%20All,which%20means%20summing%20of%20rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```
df[df['Name']!='Jon']['Sales'].sum()
```

Generalized:

```
df[df[col_name]!=exclude_variable]['Sales'].sum()
```

Comment: Thank you!  Is there a way to exclude multiple? Like if I wanted Jon and Joe excluded?

Comment: sure, `df[~df['Name'].isin(['Jon', 'Joe'])]['Sales'].sum()` note that `~` symbol inverts the boolean condition within the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Jon', 'Joe', 'Jim', 'Jerry'],
                   'Position':['Owner', 'Manager', 'Associate', 'Associate'],
                   'City':['Detroit', 'Philadelphia', 'Orlando', 'Detroit'],
                   'Sales':[200.0, 50.0, 25.0, 25.0]})


def grab_total_sales(df, base_column='Name', exclude_list=['Jim']):
    if base_column not in df.columns:
        print(f'unknown column: {base_column} not in {list(df_columns)}')
        return None
    else:
        df_ = df[~df[base_column].isin(exclude_list)]
        return df_.Sales.sum()
    return None

# print(grab_total_sales(df, base_column='Name', exclude_list=['Jim']))
# 275.0

# print(grab_total_sales(df, base_column='Position', exclude_list=['Associate']))
# 250.0 

# print(grab_total_sales(df, base_column='City', exclude_list=['Detroit']))
# 75.0
```

Comment: Thank you!  If I wanted the output in another df with 'column 1' being the 184 headers, and 'column 2' being the SUM values, would I use a loop?  In my actual dataset, I want to remove the values of "NOT STATED" and "UNKNOWN".  So I am thinking I could loop through the 184 columns use those same criteria in each one.  Thoughts?  Thank you for the help you already have provided.